# Run Springboot multi-module maven project using command

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have created a **springboot multi-module project using maven dependencies**.

I know that to run a springboot with non multi-module project using command, we just 
`mvn spring-boot:run` to run 
or `mvn clean install` to clean maven and reinstall, but for multi-module I'm kinda can't figure it out.

So I want to know if there is any configuration to run this multi-module project using **command line** since it's comfortably when I use command.

Comment: The usage `mvn clean package` and afterwards `mvn spring-boot:run` from the root should not change....

Answer (score 0):

From command line navigate to the module where you define your spring boot maven plugin ( as well as spring boot starters) and run ‘mvn  spring-boot:run’